# function that can take different type of struct C#

Tags: c#, function, struct, parameters

I have a function that needs and specific datatype as a parameter. The function looks like the following:

```
public static Color get_axis_loc_color(colormap axis, float location){
    var difRed = axis.r_end - axis.r_start;
    var difGreen = axis.g_end - axis.g_start;
    var difBlue = axis.b_end - axis.b_start;

    difRed = (int)(difRed * location) + axis.r_start;
    difGreen = (int)(difGreen * location) + axis.g_start;
    difBlue = (int)(difBlue * location) + axis.b_start;

    return new Color(a: 1, r: difRed, g: difGreen, b: difBlue);
}
```

now i have a struct that contains the colormap data like so:

```
public struct color_map  
{
    public struct x 
    {
        public static readonly int r_start =  255;
        public static readonly int g_start =  255;
        public static readonly int b_start =   255;
        public static readonly int r_end =  0;
        public static readonly int g_end =  0;
        public static readonly int b_end =  255;
    }

    public struct y
    {
        public static readonly int r_start = 255;
        public static readonly int g_start = 255;
        public static readonly int b_start =  255;
        public static readonly int r_end = 255;
        public static readonly int g_end = 0;
        public static readonly int b_end = 0;
    }

    public struct z
    {
        public static readonly int r_start = 103;
        public static readonly int g_start = 190;
        public static readonly int b_start = 155;
        public static readonly int r_end = 0;
        public static readonly int g_end = 150;
        public static readonly int b_end = 0;
    }
}
```

now when i call my function i need to be able to pass the following variables for the `colormap axis` parameter:
`colormap.x` or `colormap.y` or `colormap.z`

But i cant do this because the type doesn't match. How would i go about doing this?

If anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This wouldn't work even if you managed to create your method since the use of static fields is compiled into the code at compile time, you would have to use reflection for everything. However, since all of the structs are identical in *structure*, why don't you declare 1 struct type and 3 *variables* instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on the wrong path when it comes to designing your code here. Any answer that purports to *just* answer your question isn't going to give you the right direction.

You *can* do it using reflection but it's not going to be pretty and not going to be performant.

You could also do it using interfaces, but this would be trying to just circumvent designing the code better in the first place.

Instead, what you should do is use 1 type and 3 *variables*.

Here, let me demonstrate:

```
public struct color_map
{
    private color_map(int r1, int g1, int b1, int r2, int g2, int b2)
    {
        r_start = r1;
        g_start = g1;
        b_start = b1;
        r_end = r2;
        g_end = g2;
        b_end = b2;
    }

    public int r_start { get; }
    public int g_start { get; }
    public int b_start { get; }
    public int r_end { get; }
    public int g_end { get; }
    public int b_end { get; }

    public static readonly color_map x = new color_map(255, 255, 255, 0, 0, 255);
    public static readonly color_map y = new color_map(255, 255, 255, 255, 0, 0);
    public static readonly color_map z = new color_map(103, 190, 155, 0, 150, 0);
}
```

This would allow you to pass in a parameter of type `color_map` and access the properties.

Your `get_axis_color` method could then be declared like this (I rewrote it to use `System.Drawing.Color`, but notice that the only other change I made was to make it type a `color_map` parameter, and not `colormap`, to be in line with the structure from above):

```
public static Color get_axis_loc_color(color_map axis, float location)
{
    var difRed = axis.r_end - axis.r_start;
    var difGreen = axis.g_end - axis.g_start;
    var difBlue = axis.b_end - axis.b_start;

    difRed = (int)(difRed * location) + axis.r_start;
    difGreen = (int)(difGreen * location) + axis.g_start;
    difBlue = (int)(difBlue * location) + axis.b_start;

    return Color.FromArgb(alpha: 1, red: difRed, green: difGreen, blue: difBlue);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailled explanation! I am starting to get used to c# but sometimes my javascript behaviour comes back to confuse me :)

Comment: :) Javascript (and other "type-less" languages) and C# are quite different, they each have their strengths, but strengths in one might a weakness in another. It usually takes a mindset-shift or a paradigm-shift to be able to switch between the two successfully, best of luck with the transition and keep em' questions coming.